# How to disable one jQuery function with another one (toggle)?

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have a JS function that changes the opacity of background on search box focus.

Now, I want to make a setting option that allowes user to disable or enable it.

How can I make a disable/enable button (toggle) and save it to a cookie?

Comment: Since I don't know JS/jQuery that much I make it work with addClass and removeClass so I can disable div.

Answer (score 2):

Make a boolean variable `isOpacityToggled`.

When user clicks on a checkbox, he changes the isOpacityToggled variable.

The function you call when you focus the search input box, should check if `isOpacityToggled` on every call.

Be careful to create isOpacityToggled in a high enough scope, so you don't have scope problems.

You can use the JavaScript cookie API to save and retrieve to cookies. You could also use localStorage.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I can't do this alone. I have 0 knowledge in JS. Can it be done in jQuery also?

Comment: Never used jQuery. Can't help you.